# How to simulate from a simple point process

Tags: statistics, algorithms, simulation

Define a point process by the conditional intensity function

$$\lambda^*(t) = \mu + \alpha \sum_{t_i < t} e^{-(t-t_i)}$$

where $\mu$ and $\alpha$ are positive parameters.

I would like to simulate times from this process. Is there an explicit procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume constant timesteps of size $dt$.
The increment of a Poisson process $dq\left(t\right)$ with constant rate $\lambda$ is described
by
$$
dq\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{with probability }\lambda dt\\
0 & \text{with probability }1-\lambda dt
\end{cases}.
$$
It should be obvious that the two events $dq\left(t\right)=1$ and $dq\left(t\right)=0$ are
independent (the former corresponds to an increment in the Poisson process occurring over $\left(t,t+dt\right]$).
We take $\lambda$ to be a cadlag
approximation to $\lambda^{*}$ as demonstrated in the following code (MATLAB):

```
% T     = End time (start time is assumed to be zero)
% N     = Number of timesteps
% mu    = mu in lambda^*
% alpha = alpha in lambda^*

% List of t_i values, initially empty
t_is = [];

% Timestep size
dt = T / N;

for n = 0:(N-1)
    % Current time
    t = dt * n;

    % Compute lambda(t) = lambda^*(t)
    lambda = mu + alpha * sum( exp(t_is - t) );

    % Did an event occur?
    if rand < lambda * dt
        % It did! Add it to the list
        % This uses the left endpoint, but you could use something else
        t_is = [t_is t];
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this seems to need a calculation every time step. Is it not possible to only do a computation for every time an event occurs as you can when simulating a standard Poisson process?

Comment: It looks like people do this. This is essentially an inhomogeneous Poisson process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-homogeneous_Poisson_process#Simulation

Comment: Does "for t_i = t_is"  loop over all the values in the array/list t_is?  If so, doesn't this algorithm run in O(N^2) time?

Comment: N is the number of timesteps. The worst-case is ~N^2 (i.e. an event occurs at every timestep), but I would compute the average running time instead of the worst-case. Most (reasonable) values of lambda are small, so events are unlikely to occur at all timesteps.